# How do i correct JSONDecoderError?

Tags: python, api, flask

import requests

I am trying to send data to an API which works fine but all of a sudden i start getting JSON error

This is the code

```
def payment(phone, receiver_phone, amount):
    req_header = os.environ.get('APP_KEY')
    payload = {
        'receiver_phone': receiver_phone,
        'amount': amount,
        'payer_phone': phone
    }
    res = requests.post('https://sspay.com/payment?key={0}'.format(req_header), data=payload)
    return res.json()

print(payment('07XXXXXX', '0XXXXXXXXX', '1'))
```

This is the output i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(payment('07xxxxx', '09xxxxxxxx', '1'))
  File "test.py", line 14, in payment
    return res.json()
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/talk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/talk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 516, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/talk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "/home/pc/.virtualenvs/talk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Check what you have in `res`, I'm guessing it's empty or not json related

Comment: add a print of what you get from the API call. `print(res.content)` - it is a not a valid JSON.

Comment: Adding prints returns an internal server error

Comment: @fpietka there is a similar API call from another endpoint and it returns a JSON value as expected. i really dont know why this one is giving error

Answer (score 0):

use the code below - it will make you to find the issue

```
req_header = os.environ.get('APP_KEY')
res = requests.post('https://sspay.com/payment?key={0}'.format(req_header), data=payload)
if res.status_code == 200:
    data = res.json()
    return data
else:
    print('We have a problem. status code : {}'.format(res.status_code))
```

- you are not checking the API response (status code)
- what if `req_header` is None

Comment: the response is "we have a problem. status code : 500"

Comment: so the API you are calling has an error. you can't probably do much about it, you should contact them.

Comment: add a print of `res.text` as well.

Comment: res.txt returns an HTML formated internal server error

Comment: what is this API - does it have a public documents?